# How to troubleshoot why I cannot connect to Samba Server

Tags: windows, samba

I am trying to connect to a Samba Server from Windows. I configured it accoring to the Ubuntu Docs for [CLients](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide) & [Servers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide) using CLI.

```
[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browseable = yes
writable = yes
create mash = 0755
directory mask = 0755
valid users = %S
```

sudo smbpasswd -a jm
sudo smbpasswd -e jm

Then

```
sudo reload smbd
```

On Windows, I did:

1. map network drive
2. \IP_OF_SERVER\USERNAME
3. Connect with different credentials -> entered my Ubuntu Credentials
4. Was prompted for credentials again, without errors ...

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards